# How to show the console in the Chrome developer tools sources view

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How can I display the console while in the sources tab for the Chrome developer tools?

It has opened that way for me, so I know it is possible, but if it doesn’t display when I open it, I can get it to.

Comment: The selected answer is out of date. Please re-select.

Comment: @P i: What answer (the accepted answer may or may not have changed in the meantime)? In what way is it out of date?

Comment: The current accepted answer contained *"in the accepted answer"*, so apparently it changed.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I couldn't find the <kbd>Show drawer</kbd> button stated in [Marten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652701/how-to-show-the-console-in-chrome-developer-tools-sources-view/32652848#32652848).  Perhaps it has been removed in the past year and a half.  I found it in the "three vertical dots" options menu on the top right though.

Also this can be toggled with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: Esc key is magic. Thank you.

Comment: Re *"three vertical dots options menu"*: [Hamburger menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button)? Or perhaps there is another name for it.

Answer (score 82):

In the top right of the stack inspector, click on the "⋮" next to the "x". Then, click "Show console drawer". You can also hit the Escape key.

[image: In the top right of the stack inspector, click on the "⋮" next to the "x"]. [image: click "Show console drawer].

Comment: This is still valid as of today.  You can see how it would be easy to accidentally toggle off if you use the escape key a lot.

Comment: The pictures are very helpful, but they are also very large, and do not both fit on my screen at the same time (pretty standard 4:3 desktop monitor). If you could resize them such that they were small enough to be visible simultaneously, this would be the best answer here.

Answer (score 46):

I think you were looking for the "Show drawer" button. It looks like

```
>_
```

It is three places left of the devtool close (x) button.

Comment: Now it's inside the menu triggered by the vertical ```(...)``` button.

1 place left of the devtool close ```x``` button

Comment: Simply press "Esc" :) while you are in "Sources" tab

Comment: @Dhanuka Yeah because that is intuitive.  Press escape to open a window?  Geez google

Comment: No longer the correct answer, you click press exc or toggle the drawer from the 3 dot menu item on the toolbar

Answer (score 26):

I can never find it either when I accidentally turn it off.  Here's an updated screenshot from Chrome, Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit).  It's next to the Settings button in the top right corner, underneath the Close icon.  Click the vertical ellipsis, then you will see the option, **Show console drawer**.

[image: ![Show console drawer]

Answer (score 5):

You can use a keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tilde</kbd> to show *Console*.

Note: Tilde is the `~` key between <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys.

Comment: Re *"Tilde is the ~ key between Esc and Tab keys."*: Only on an American keyboard layout. Not even on a [UK keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QWERTY_keyboard_language_variants#United_Kingdom).

Answer (score 2):

If you have any errors or warnings showing in the top bar next to the three vertical dots, simply clicking on these indicators will also open the drawer, but the simplest way to toggle it is simply pressing Esc, like others have noted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it. It doesn't work...

And me, I work on the API script and I'm not very operational on this language.

For the test of my development on API SCRIPT, I use a right "console" window concerning the information, error message, etc. Here the screen of this window is empty while we vote the number of error messages, etc. And in addition, I put a lot of "console.log" in my procedures.

Surely, I made a manipulation error on the keyboard.
So how can we display the consoles?
Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: That is a very busy screenshot. It [ought to](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72895537/edit) have [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) to point out the important information. I am serious. You can [edit (change) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72895537/edit). (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)